# Finite $\epsilon$ net property implies Heine Borel compact in complete metric space.

Tags: general-topology

Studying for a prelim and would like some help with this old prelim problem

Suppose that $(X,d)$ is a complete metric space. $A\subset X$ has the finite $\epsilon$ net property if for each $\epsilon>0$ there are finitely many points $x_i$ in $A$ such that $A\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^k B_\epsilon(x_i)$ Prove that  a closed subset $A\subset X$ is Heine Borel compact iff it has the finite epsilon net property.

I think one direction is easy (assuming Ive done it correctly) Assume $A$ is compact. Cover $A$ with balls of size $\epsilon$. Then there is a finite sub cover. I think this is all thats needed for the forward direction.

But for the reverse, I'm having some difficulty. I assume that $A$ has the finite epsilon net property and that I'm given an open cover $C$ of $A$. Now I want to produce a finite sub cover. I start by saying that, for each $x\in A$ there is some $U_x\in C$ such that $x\in U_x$. Since $U_x$ is open, there is some $\epsilon>0$ such that $B_\epsilon(x)\subset U_x$. Now, I want to say that each  open set $U\in C$ which contains $x$ may be replaced by $U_x$. Also, since $A$ has the finite epsilon property, we can also say that the open cover $\{B_\epsilon(x)\}_{x\in A}$ has a finite sub cover $\{B_\epsilon(x_i)\}_{i=1}^k$ so that any set $U$ which contains $x_i$ can be replaced by a single representative $U_{x_i}$. But it might be that none of the other open sets contain any of the $x_i$ and this approach is seeming too complicated and doesn't seem to use the completeness of $X$ or the closeness of $A$. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Added comment: I think this would be much easier with sequential compactness. But the problem says Heine-Borel compact, which I think, for a complete metric space is the same as sequential compact. But from the statement of the problem its not clear if this would be allowed.

Comment: Proving sequential compactness is indeed easier. If I were taking such a prelim, I’d do that, and then if I had enough time, I’d come back and prove that sequential compactness implies compactness in metric spaces.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not surprised you're having trouble proving this! The reverse direction as stated is false: $(0, 1)$ has finite $\epsilon$-nets for every positive $\epsilon$.

Maybe this is stated only for *closed* $A\subset X$?

---

EDIT: Ah, this makes more sense now. Here's a hint: for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, let $A_n=\{a^n_1, . . . , a^n_{k_n}\}$ be a finite ${2^{-n}}$-net. Then we can represent every point $x$ in $A$ as the limit of a Cauchy sequence $x_1, x_2, . . . $ with $x_i\in A_i$; and since $X$ is complete and $A$ is closed, every such sequence corresponds to a point in $A$.

This lets us represent $A$ as (a quotient of) the set of paths through a certain finitely branching tree: $T$ is the set of sequences $(y_1, y_2, . . . )$ such that

- $y_i\in A_i$, and
- $d(y_i, y_{i+1})<2^{1-i}$.

Now I suspect you've seen the space of paths through a finitely branching tree before (HINT: Cantor space), and the result that the quotient of a compact space is compact . . .

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to include that $A$ is closed. I will make this correction.

Comment: I think I understand what your saying, and I appreciate the response, however I was looking for a more straightforward method. I know that this can be proved using only elementary techniques and since Im still learning, it would be helpful if you or someone else could provide some more straightforward hints.